# Тире в предложении "Странный вопрос (—) ты сама должна понимать, думаю"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужна ли постановка тире в данном предложении: "Странный вопрос — ты сама должна понимать, думаю"? Если да, то объясните почему.

Answer (score 1):

**СтрАнный вопрос — (это) ты сама должна понимать, думаю.**

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

9. Тире ставится, если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой **присоединительное предложение**, перед ней ставится тире (возможно вставить слово ***это***, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении): На стене ни одного образа — дурной знак (Л.);

В первой части инверсия подлежащего и сказуемого (вопрос странный).

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, связь межу двумя частями этого предложения — присоединение, оно допукает постановку запятой или тире, при отсутствии союза часто используется тире. ([Присоединительные члены предложения](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html))

**Странный вопрос — ты сама должна понимать, думаю.**

Сравните (добавлен союз): *Странный вопрос, да ты сама должна понимать, думаю.*

По воле автора можно иначе расставить акценты: считать вторую часть добавочным замечанием и поместить его в скобки.

**Странный вопрос (ты сама должна понимать, думаю).**

> Поверьте (совесть в том порукой), супружество нам будет мукой. (Пушкин)